# How to recompile old Spring 2.5 application?

Tags: java, spring, java-7

We have in use an old application running on Spring 2.5 and Jboss 4.2.3 which hasn't been modified for years. It will be replaced with a new application, developed in our current stack, in a foreseable future. Until then, we need to provide very basic maintenance and updates.

I have succeded to setup a working development environment with newer JRE and MySQL versions. Now I need to test that we are able to modify the original source and recompile it the WAR package for deployment.

I would appreciate information on the following topics:

- Which JDK version should I use? Can I use Java 7 or do I need a 1.6 version?
- Where can I find build scripts or samples? (there's nothing such as build.xml in the project).
- Any other tip that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to hire someone to do this; this is far too broad a question, and not easy to answer even remotely correct without access to the current sources.

Comment: "Which JDK version should I use?" - use the same JDK which was used previously. If it's a legacy project and is going to be replaced, then there's no point to upgrade JDK.

Comment: "Where can I find build scripts or samples?" - search the internet for "Ant tutorial", "build.xml example", "Maven tutorial" or "pom.xml example".

Comment: The newest JDK (1.8)  should be compatible with the one used when your application was developed. For the remaining of your questions, you should publish at least a tree view of the files in the project.